# Macbook Air keyboard doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, restore, trackpad

I have had my Macbook Air for nearly a year now. I have never had a Mac before but have enjoyed it. I cannot get my keyboard to work anymore. I have read up and rebooted it, have tried it in safe mode but am too frightened to mess around with safe mode. I want to get it back to factory settings......But I can't get my head round how to do it. I am typing this on my Nexus.....Can someone help me, I need it in real simple terms.....PS I am in my sixties..Not Mac Book savvy!

Comment: When you say "you cannot get your keyboard to work" is it that the whole keyboard is dead, or just some keys?  Have you tried using an external (USB) keyboard?  That would be the first thing I would try.

Comment: Does your keyboard not type anything at all?  Or just type strange characters like åß∂ƒ© instead of asdfg?